# Check mutliple mxf files for errors

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, syntax

Im trying to do a powershell to test all the files in a folder for any errors using ffmpeg, as follows.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.mxf" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    ffmpeg -v error -i $_.FullName -map 0:1 -f null 2>$($_.FullName + '.log') E:\$_.FullName.mxf
}
```

I get an error as follows

```
ffmpeg : At least one output file must be specified At line:2 char:5
+     ffmpeg -v error -i $_.FullName -map 0:1 -f null }
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (At least one ou...st be specified:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I actually dont need the output here, just want to check the file for any errors.

Comment: Note: While https://stackoverflow.com/q/11400248/45375 is related, its focus is different (metadata display without video-data processing). Here, the intent is to actually process the data, but not produce an output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface:

- Your error message - unlike your command - implies that you did *not* also pass `E:\$_.FullName.mxf` to your `ffmpeg` command as the last argument.
- If you had, your command would have worked, for the reasons explained below.
- As an aside: As an actual  output file path  `E:\$_.FullName.mxf`  wouldn't work, because `$_` (alone) would expand to the input file's full path, so you'd get a path such as
  `E:\C:\path\to\...`, which is invalid; also `.FullName` would be retained *verbatim*, because the argument is implicitly treated as if it were enclosed in `"..."`, i.e. as an
  [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), inside of which *expressions* (as opposed to stand-alone variable references such as `$_`), such
  as accessing a property, must be enclosed in `$(...)`.

---

- **`-f null`** means that you're using the so-called **null muxer**, whose **express purpose is *not to write an output file*** (but the input file's data is still processed).
- Despite that, **`ffmpeg` nonetheless requires you to specify an output-file operand** - even though it is effectively *ignored*.
- Therefore, you can pass a *dummy* operand to satisfy this syntax requirement, in the simplest case `-`:

```
# Note the "-" as the dummy output-file operand.
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.mxf" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  ffmpeg -v error -i $_.FullName -map 0:1 -f null - 2>($_.FullName + '.log')
}
```

Note:

- **If you were to specify an *actual video format* with `-f`**, e.g, `-f mov`, yet still wanted to discard the output, **you'd have to use `/dev/null` (on Unix) / `NUL` (on Windows)** as the output-file operand,
  **Additionally, use `-y` on Unix-like platforms** to suppress a spurious prompt for "overwriting" `/dev/null` (observed with v6 of `ffmpeg`).
- In *Windows PowerShell*, `ffmpeg`'s *first* stderr line (if any) is mistakenly recorded in the output file *as if it were a PowerShell error*, i.e. in a noisy, multiline format (fortunately, this problem has been fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)).

  - This is simply a *cosmetic* problem and can be ignored.
  - If you want to prevent the problem, use the following workaround (for an explanation of the technique, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45288514/45375)):

    ```
    Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.mxf" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
      $stdErrLines = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] @()
      ffmpeg -v error -i $_.FullName -map 0:1 -f null - 2>&1 |
        ForEach-Object {
          if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) {
            $stdErrLines.Add($_.ToString())
          } else {
            $_
          }
        }
      $stdErrLines >($_.FullName + '.log')
    }
    ```

Comment: This works well, but i get an error in the log file `FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError`

Comment: Glad to hear it, @user726720. The error isn't an error, just an (unfortunate) cosmetic issue. Please see my update, which shows you how to avoid the problem (which takes more work). Another option is to simply ignore it.